# Android : Realign layout after screen keyboard auto suggestions complete

Tags: android, imageview

I hope that makes sense...

Basically when the on screen keyboard appears and then the auto suggestions as well, it pushes my view up the screen - a graphic in an imageView that I would like to persist.

When the auto complete is over and done with, the screen stays where is is despite the auto suggest disappearing.

Is there any way to let my layout reclaim that space and simply go back down again into the empty space ?  ie to float back down again ?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, try adding the following line to the `<activity>` in your manifest:

```
<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        ...
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        ...>
    ...
    </activity>
...
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Nope that made no difference unfortunately. I am making a chatbot. I have an image at the top, a TextView for the bot's reply and an EditView for the user's questions. When the onscreen keyboard appears it forces everything up the page and even more so when the auto suggest comes up. So then I can only see half of the image. I'd like it to scroll back down again once the auto suggest finishes.  I hope I explained that better.

Comment: hm, try `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"`

Comment: Sadly not, it's just the same.  I think I am just going to have to reduce the height of the image (groans).

Comment: sadly, no. I had similar problem but what I've suggested solved my case